# pandas drop row if value is not in different dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes and want to drop rows from dataframe 'Total' if there is not a matching ID in dataframe 'Student'

DF Total:

```
    ID     name
0   115    john
1   118    mike
2   34     mac
3   897    sarah
```

DF Student:

```
    ID     name
0   34     mac
1   118    mike
2   897    sarah
```

In this example since ID 115 is not present in the Student df that row would be dropped from df Total and the resulting table would look like this:

```
    ID     name
0   118    mike
1   34     mac
2   897    sarah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to use the .isin() method:

```
df_total[df_total['ID'].isin(df_student['ID'])]
```